# How to save a list of string in sublists according specific expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist, path

I'm doing a script to save a read path in sublist. Let's suppose I have 400 file paths saved in a list, every path has the specific syntax `Ci_whaterver.csv`, then in my pathlist I have something like this:

```
pathlist=[C1_01.csv,C1_02.csv,...,Cn_01.csv,Cn_02.csv]
```

I would like to have finally a `pathlistf` ordered or sort with this situation:

```
pathlistf=[[C1_01.csv,C1_02.csv,...],[C2_01.csv,C2_02.csv,...],...,[Cn_01.csv,Cn_02.csv,...]]
```

I don't have idea to reorder the path to this way.

Hello again, i got this problem:
I would like to ask something very similar to the past case, let suppose i have the next path: 
`path=[case1_Qxxx_cap1_whatever.csv,case1_Qxxx_cap1_whatever2.csv,case1_Qxxx_cap1_whatever3.csv,....,case1_Qxxx_cap2_whatever.csv,case1_Qxxx_cap2_whatever2.csv,case1_Qxxx_cap2_whatever3.csv,case2_Qxxx_cap1_whatever.csv,case2_Qxxx_cap1_whatever2.csv,...,case2_Qxxx_cap2_whatever.csv,case2_Qxxx_cap2_whatever2.csv]`

I would like to have this:

`pathf=[[[case1_Qxxx_cap1_whatever.csv,case1_Qxxx_cap1_whatever2.csv,...],[case1_Qxxx_cap2_whatever.csv,Qxxx_cap2_whatever2.csv,...]],[[case2_Qxxx_cap1_whatever.csv,case2_Qxxx_cap1_whatever2.csv,...],[case2_Qxxx_cap2_whatever.csv,case2_Qxxx_cap2_whatever2.csv,...]]]`

Comment: _I don't have idea to reorder the path to this way_ You have no idea whatsoever where to start?

Answer (score 0):

One way will be to create a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and use the part `Ci` as key and lists of file names starting with `Ci` will be the value. For example, take `pathlist = ['C1_01.csv','C1_02.csv', 'C2_01.csv' , 'C3_01.csv', 'C2_02.csv']`, then we will create a dictionary which will store

```
{'C1': ['C1_01.csv', 'C1_02.csv'], 'C2': ['C2_01.csv', 'C2_02.csv'], 'C3': ['C3_01.csv']}
```

Here is the code:

```
pathlist = ['C1_01.csv','C1_02.csv', 'C2_01.csv' , 'C3_01.csv', 'C2_02.csv']
d = {}
for path in pathlist:
    if path[:2] not in d:
        d[path[:2]] = [path]
    else:
        d[path[:2]].append(path)
pathlistf = []
for key in d:
    pathlistf.append(d[key])
print(pathlistf)
# Output: [['C1_01.csv', 'C1_02.csv'], ['C3_01.csv'], ['C2_01.csv', 'C2_02.csv']]
```

Hope this solves the problem. Feel free to ask any doubt.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, that's exactly what i want, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If `pathlist` is pre-sorted, you can use the following code based on the [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```py
from itertools import groupby
pathlist=['Cn_01.csv', 'C1_02.csv', 'C9_01.csv', 'C9_02.csv', 'Ca_01.csv', 'C9_03.csv', 'Ca_02.csv', 'C1_01.csv', 'Cn_02.csv']
pathlist.sort()
groupedfilenames = (list(g) for _, g in groupby(pathlist, key=lambda a: a[:2]))
print(list(groupedfilenames))
```

Output:

```
[['C1_01.csv', 'C1_02.csv'], ['C9_01.csv', 'C9_02.csv', 'C9_03.csv'], ['Ca_01.csv', 'Ca_02.csv'], ['Cn_01.csv', 'Cn_02.csv']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this function help you?

Best!

```py
import traceback
import pandas as pd
from typing import List


def organize_paths(path_lst:List[str],sep:str):
    """
    Method to create a DataFrame from csv_path items
    Args:
        path_lst (List[str]): lits with paths in string format
        sep (str): separator for split method
    Returns:
        df (DataFrame): matrix with the splitting info
    """
    lst = list()
    print(f'(SUCCESS organize_paths) -> starting process -> input: ({path_lst},{sep})')
    try:
        for item in path_lst:
            calc_data = item.split(sep)
            lst.append({calc_data[0]:calc_data[1]})
        df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
        print(f'(SUCCESS organize_paths) -> finishing process -> input: ({path_lst},{sep}) -> output sample: {df.head().to_dict()}')
        return df
    except BaseException as exc:
        print(f'(ERROR organize_paths) -> finishing process -> input: ({path_lst},{sep}) -> exception: {traceback.format_exc()}')
        
pathlist=['C1_01.csv','C1_02.csv','C2_01.csv','C2_02.csv']
df = organize_paths(path_lst=pathlist,sep='_') 
# display(df) to validate calculations
```